# How to handle sport race time results formatting in SQL, preferrably MariaDB

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

Timetaking in many sports/competitions is typically accurate down to `1/100th` of a second, some even down to `1/1000th` of a second.

A couple of random examples from swimming, which uses `1/100th` second accuracy (in the format `'minutes:seconds,100th of second'`):

```
50m Backstroke 00:34,12

1500m Freestyle 18:49,02
```

The delimiter after the seconds field may be either comma or dot - both are seen in professional timetaking systems.

How is this formatting achieved in SQL / MariaDB and what field type should be used? I believe that it is necessary to use `1/1000` of a second accuracy when entering data but format the output to `1/100th` in the query.

Comment: You can use the [TIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html) datatype

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use MySQL/MariaDB `TIME`.
See [Fractional Seconds in Time Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fractional-seconds.html)

Your example above could be done like this (with `result TIME(2)`):

```sql
CREATE TABLE `swimming_race` (
    `swimmer_id` INT (10) unsigned NOT NULL
    ,`distance` SMALLINT (5) unsigned NOT NULL
    ,`style` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
    ,`result` TIME(2) NOT NULL
    );

INSERT INTO `swimming_race` (
    `swimmer_id`
    ,`distance`
    ,`style`
    ,`result`
    )
VALUES (
    '1'
    ,'50'
    ,'Backstroke'
    ,'0:00:34.12'
    )
    ,(
    '1'
    ,'1500'
    ,'Freestyle'
    ,'0:18:49.02'
    );
```

[image: data in table after insert]

Comment: This is the exact way I have set up the tables :) the `TIME(2)` was all I was missing.

Comment: Is there a manner in which to default format the time field without the `hours` part? I'll only need the hours in connection with Open Water (10 kilometer) events, which is a somewhat rare occurance.

Comment: @DavDav use [TIME_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) for the output. `SELECT TIME_FORMAT(result, '%i:%s.%f') as short_res FROM swimming_race`

Comment: Use `TIME(3)` to get 3 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestions. Formatting using `datetime(2)` is one option which will work, but the date part is not needed.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT CONVERT('2019-04-01 00:03:19.3200000',datetime(2));
+----------------------------------------------------+
| CONVERT('2019-04-01 00:03:19.3200000',datetime(2)) |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| 2019-04-01 00:03:19.32                             |
+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.005 sec)
```

Using `TIME(2)` as my data type was spot on.

Out of historical interest only: When was this implemented in MariaDB / MySQL? I looked into a similiar issue 5-6 years ago but back then I was not able to find this :)

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

`TIME(3)` for storing.

`REPLACE(col, ',', '.')` before converting to `TIME(3)` so that commas will be turned into periods and not trip up the conversion.

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT('0:1:23.456', TIME(3));
+--------------------------------+
| CONVERT('0:1:23.456', TIME(3)) |
+--------------------------------+
| 00:01:23.456                   |
+--------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT CONVERT('0:1:23,456', TIME(3));
+--------------------------------+
| CONVERT('0:1:23,456', TIME(3)) |
+--------------------------------+
| 00:01:23.000                   |   -- lost fraction because of comma
+--------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                      |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect time value: '0:1:23,456' |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Completed examples:

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT(REPLACE('0:1:23,456', ',', '.'), TIME(3));
+---------------------------------------------------+
| CONVERT(REPLACE('0:1:23,456', ',', '.'), TIME(3)) |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| 00:01:23.456                                      |
+---------------------------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT CONVERT(REPLACE('0:1:23,456', ',', '.'), TIME(3)) with_comma;
+--------------+
| with_comma   |
+--------------+
| 00:01:23.456 |
+--------------+

mysql> SELECT CONVERT(REPLACE('0:1:23.456', ',', '.'), TIME(3)) with_dot;
+--------------+
| with_dot     |
+--------------+
| 00:01:23.456 |
+--------------+

mysql> SELECT CONVERT(REPLACE('0:1:23.45', ',', '.'), TIME(3)) with_2_digits;
+---------------+
| with_2_digits |
+---------------+
| 00:01:23.450  |
+---------------+
```